# Using R's bquote with a variable, but keeping it evaluated as a string?

Tags: r

Let's say I have

```
a <- "some string"
```

Calling

```
bquote(a==.(a))
```

gives a different result than

```
bquote(a=="some string")
```

namely, it tries to represent the string as symbols. Can I reference a variable but have it keep it "string-like" nature?

Comment: @akrun sorry I meant in a plot, like plot(c(1,1), xlab=bquote(a==.(a))), and the differences are visible when I save it as a pdf using a font like Palatino

Comment: I tried by saving in a pdf.  Couldn't find any difference with font specified as `Palatino`

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron - You should add all relevant details to your question.